# Android Eclipse project compilation errors with maven provided dependency

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I'm converting an android application to be maven-based

what I've done is:
Insert pom.xml

1. List item
2. copy java classes into main/java directory and make this directory
   the source path
3. insert the maven nature into .project file

I add the google android library dependency into pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
   <artifactId>android</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I then realised that I don't need the android library to be included in the class path as I'm actually refering it from the pom.xml

So I removed the library, and what happend is the the project has compilation errors, though It exports the apk successfully when I right click > Run As> Maven Install, and this means that this project is a correct project from a maven perspective, so what's wrong with eclipse ??

What I found is that the Maven Dependency Library is abscent when I set the library scope as provided,

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

but is back when I set the dependency to it's default(Compile),

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```

Though this scope makes maven fail to package as this library is a core library that must not be included, and anyway I find it a terrible solution even if it's packaging well

What am I missing here ??

NB: I'm using MotoDev IDE

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there is an issue with the android-maven-plugin with apk packaging ... will post the solution when solved

Comment: Is this something we should adjust in the Eclipse for Mobile Developers package? I initially put the Maven support plugins in the package, but then removed them after doing an informal survey of users. You're using m2e-android?

Comment: yes I'm doing, I posted the same question on the plugin group and they told me that the provided scope is not included in the classpath. Don't know why